# django and ajax - data not returning list values

Tags: ajax, django

The ajax request is sent when a user clicks a navigation bar list element. It redirects after the request is processed. The value I am trying to send is an array of an array.

I get the data to return a list and print it in the terminal in django. It always shows a list that is empty.

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def color_pick_stats(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        colors_lst = request.POST.getlist('colors')
        print(colors_lst)
        return render(request, 'stats/statistics.html')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'stats/statistics.html')
```

html

```
<li class="list-element"><a href="{% url 'statistics' %}" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;"><span onclick="sendData()">Statistics</span></a></li>
```

javascript

```
function sendData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { colors: color_pick },
    success: () => {
      console.log('success');
    },
    error: (xhr,errmsg,err) =>  {
      console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
    }
  })
}
```

When I alert the values of the list color_pick in javascript it gives the correct values. In django when printed in terminal the values do not return and the list is returned as empty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use **render** here. Use `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')` like this. Here **data** will be a dict.

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal what does this do exactly?

Comment: You need to return your response to ajax call in json format. That's why I suggested this way.